# Schedule requests to IIS using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, aws-lambda

I have been struggling around this for some time now, I have seen there are many options to make schedules request to APIS through AWS but I could not make it work.
My case is to make a **external** schedule request do an API that is inside IIS on an EC2 instance.
Could someone please tell me what is the best approach to make it work? Do I need an AWS VPC or CloudWatch? There is no way of doing it directly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lambda with a `cron` trigger with the schedule you want to create.

Lambda can make a call to IIS at the scheduled time.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Hope it helps.